# how to copy custom AMI from one AWS account to another

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ami

I have created custom AMI using packer and saved into one AWS account, now I want to copy same AMI into another AWS account.

Can anyone help here to achieve this?

I have tried

```
aws ec2 copy-image --name "${AMI_Name}" --source-image-id "${AMI_ID}" --source-region "us-west-2" --copy-image-tags
```

but I am confused as I didn't provide the destination information

Comment: Why not share the AMI directly the Packer configuration?

Comment: Read this - https://medium.com/@praveenraghav01/aws-clone-copy-ami-across-accounts-183e2b311063

Comment: When copying an AMI, you can only "pull" the AMI from another account that acts as the 'source'. The destination is always the account that made the request. It's like saying "please give ME a copy of this particular AMI".

Answer (score 1):

**copy-image** command does not copy ami's across accounts, it does **across regions** within same account.

In order to use an ami in different account, you need to share it with another account by `edit ami permissions` from the UI and adding the account id that you want to share the ami with, or instead use the following command

> aws ec2 modify-image-attribute 
> --image-id <<ami_id>> 
> --launch-permission "Add=[{UserId=<<remote_account_id>>}]"